# Switch layout/start activity in hierarchy of objects

Tags: android, design-patterns, android-activity

I am writing event based android application in which I start main thread which receives some message may be from server or some third party service.. 
I have created handler to handle message.. that handler forwards to appropriate handler and so on.. its kind of multilevel message forwarding.. [it looks like state pattern].

Problem I am facing is the lowest leaf of handler which handles message cant access to UI...
if i forward context to that level then also i cant change layout...

Please let me know the pattern I should follow to resolve this issue.. 
[ i am not aware much abt activities (new to android development)]

Thanks in advance,
knocker

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats the correct pattern, the use of handlers are indicated for the application type you wrote, many operations on background threads or services sending messages to the main event thread to show operations progress or results, so, the handler that update the gui must be declared in the main event thread and must the the only one to do that operation. The others handlers are running on diferents threads with differents messages queue and only post or send messages to the main handler, so you don´t have to touch anything from the UI.

The ´main´ handler must be declared in the main event thread and will be the only one who touch the ui.

cheer